# Error 403 and 401 when trying to retrieve tweets with R. Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-api-v2, rtweet

I have pretty basic knowledge in **R**. A few months ago, I used this simple code with the package Rtweet to retrieve tweets using my credentials of the Twitter API.

```
library(rtweet)
library(igraph)
library(tidyverse)

token <- create_token(
  app = "name",
  consumer_key = "XXXXXXXXXX",
  consumer_secret = "XXXXXXXXXX",
  access_token = "XXXXXXXXXX",
  access_secret = "XXXXXXXXXX")


tweets <- search_tweets("search", n=50, type= "mixed", retryonratelimit = TRUE)
```

Since the API changes I cannot use this code anymore. When I try to run the code, I get a 403 error: “You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level.” I paid for the basic tier of the API and my app is attached to a project and I keep getting this error. Also, I tried resetting my tokens. What am I doing wrong?

Also, I tried another method of authentication, this function just asks me to type my bearer token:

```
auth <- rtweet_app()
tweets_libros <- search_tweets("libros sep", n=50, type= "mixed", retryonratelimit = TRUE, token = auth)
```

It gave me the same error.

Do you know if I am doing something wrong? Or just with the new changes the Twitter API just went nuts?

And, since I only know how to connect to the Twitter (or X) API with Rtweet, I asked Bard to give me a code to do so without the Rtweet package:

```
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

# Set your Twitter API keys and secrets
consumer_key <- "XXXXXXXXXX"
consumer_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXX"
access_token <- "XXXXXXXXXX"
access_token_secret <- "XXXXXXXXXX"

# Create the authentication header
bearer_token <- paste0("Bearer ", access_token)
headers <- c(Authorization = bearer_token)

# Search for tweets about "rstats" and limit the results to 10 tweets
url <- "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?q=rstats&n=10"
response <- httr::GET(url, headers = headers)

# Check the response status code
if (response$status_code == 200) {
  # The request was successful
  tweets <- jsonlite::fromJSON(content(response, "text"))
  print(tweets)
} else {
  # The request failed
  print(paste("Error:", response$status_code))
}
```

I don't know how the code above works, but i tried replacing "bearer" with my bearer token and still this does not works. When I run the code above it returns me the 401 error.

Answer (score 0):

You paid for the API access via OAuth 2.0 but you don't use it. That's why you keep getting the same error.

Read the [authentication vignette](https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/articles/auth.html)  to use the Oauth 2.0 , which basically says to use `rtweet_client` and `rtweet_oauth2` to obtain the authentications.
Once you get the token you'll need to use [`tweet_search_recent`](https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/reference/tweet_search_recent.html) or [`tweet_search_all`](https://docs.ropensci.org/rtweet/reference/tweet_search_all.html) because these functions are the ones that use the API v2.

Note that I would recommend to install the httr2 devel version and the rtweet from github (from the devel branch) if you want a painless experience with the authentication.